# surjective map from $S^1 \to S^1$ which is null-homotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to find a surjective map $f:S^1 \to S^1$ which is null-homotopic. Its trivial to see that if a map is surjective then it will definitely be null-homotopic since $S^1 \setminus a$ is homeomorphic to real line but I am looking for a surjective map which is null-homotopic.

I was thinking about the identity map but I cannot extend it to $D^2$ yet, so I am not sure.

Now I am thinking something like

> A map from $S^1 \to X$ is nothing but a path in $X$. So choose a path starting at $(0,1)$ then going in the clockwise direction to $(0,1)$ and then coming back from $(0,1)$ back to $(0,1)$ in the anticlockwise direction. Simply put $\gamma$ is a path loop around $(0,1)$ and then I am considering the path $\beta=\gamma * \gamma^{-1}$ where $*$ denotes the join of two paths.

What do you think?

P.S-I think I need a simpler path which can be extended to $D^2 \to D^2$. So I need to choose another simpler path.

Comment: Technically, a map  $S^1\to X$ is a loop, not a path.

Comment: A more direct $f$ is $f(z)=e^{i\pi\operatorname{Re} z}.$ Basically, any map $p:S^1\to\mathbb R$ is null homotopic, and if $p$ is not constant, the range is a closed interval, and we can scale that closed interval to make the length at least $2\pi$ and then use the usual map: $\mathbb R\to S^1$ of $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ to make it onto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity map is not nullhomotopic (in $S^1$). If it were, then by definition $S^1$ would be contractible and $\pi_n(S^1)=0$ for all $n$, which is false. Famously, $\pi_1(S^1)=\Bbb Z$.

But, take a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$: $\gamma:I\to S^1,\,t\mapsto\exp(2\pi it)$ based at $(1,0)$. The loop $\lambda=(\gamma)^{-1}\cdot\gamma$ - in the notation of the fundamental group action - *is* surjective but it is also nullhomotopic, as you seem to have guessed.

Explicitly: $$\lambda(t)=\begin{cases}\gamma(2t)&0\le t\le\frac{1}{2}\\\gamma(2(1-t))&\frac{1}{2}\le t\le1\end{cases}$$With nullhomotopy given by: $$H:I\times I\to S^1,\,(t,u)\mapsto\begin{cases}\gamma(2t\cdot u)&0\le t\le\frac{1}{2}\\\gamma(2(1-t)\cdot u)&\frac{1}{2}\le t\le 1\end{cases}$$

Note that $H(0,u)=H(1,u)$ for all $u$ and $H(t,0)=(1,0),H(t,1)=\lambda(t)$ for all values of $t$ and $u$. Using $S^1\cong I/\partial I$, we find: $$\lambda:S^1\to S^1$$Which is surjective and: $$H:S^1\times I\to S^1$$A (based) nullhomotopy of $\lambda$ (and $H$ does extend to a map on $D^2$).

---

Since $D^2\cong S^1\times I/(S^1\times\{0\})$ ($D^2$ is homeomorphic to the *cone* of $S^1$), by the universal mapping property of a quotient we know $H$ factors through $D^2$. It is a good exercise to explicitly construct the map $D^2\to S^1$ and to explicitly construct the quotient map $S^1\times I\twoheadrightarrow D^2$.

Comment: but the question paper further asks to extend it to $D^2 \to S^1$ but how can I do it?

Comment: Any null homotopic map from $S^{1}\to Y$ extends to a map from $D^{2}\to Y$ .

Comment: @permutation_matrix I give a brief overview at the bottom. That question (which isn't quite the one you originally asked) has been answered in more detail elsewhere

Comment: @permutation_matrix In fact a map from $S^{1}$ extends to a map from $D^{2}$ if and only if it is null homotopic. See Munkres Topology (Lemma 55.3)

Answer (score 2):

Let $p:t\in\mathbb R\mapsto e^{2\pi it}\in S^1$ be the usual covering map and let $g:S^1\to\mathbb R$ be any continuous function whose image contains the interval $[0,800]$. The composition $p\circ g$ is surjective and nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work. Essentially, any loop that traces a rout and then reverses back is null homotopic.

A direct such $f$ can be found if you define $p(x,y)=x$ on $D^1.$

Then $p(D^1)$ and $p(S^1)$ are both $[-1,1].$

If we define:

$$F(x,y)=(\cos(\pi p(x,y)),\sin(\pi p(x,y))$$

We get a map: $F: D^1\to S^1$ continuous, and $f=F_{\mid S^1}:S^1\to S^1$ is onto and continuous and null homotopic.

---

If we think of $S^1$ as being a subset of the complex plane, this can be rewritten as:

$$F(z)=e^{i\pi\operatorname{Re} z}$$

---

We can start with literally any non-constant $p:S^1\to \mathbb R.$ Then the range is some non-trivial closed interval $[a,b],$ and we can choose:

$$f(z)=e^{2i\pi p(z)/(b-a)}.$$

---

Perhaps more interestingly, all null-homotopic maps $S^1\to S^1$ can be gotten this way. This is due to the "universal cover" property of the map $\mathbb R\to S^1,$ $x\mapsto e^{ix}$